# Couldn't find Movie without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

App has 2 simple models and I use [TMDb api](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb). Movie & MovieReviews. When I try to to visit this URL

```
localhost:3000/movies/%23<Tmdb::Movie:0x007ff0608f4398>/movie_reviews/new
```

where I should see the form for submitting reviews, I get the error. Also, the url seems kinda bad. How can I get the movie id? It also shows

```
 parameters:
 {"movie_id"=>"#<Tmdb::Movie:0x007ff0608f4398>"}
```

and this is MovieReviewsController#new

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movie_review = @movie.movie_reviews.new
end
```

[Source code](https://github.com/Xantax/sample_movies)

Comment: can you add your new.html.erb content please

Comment: https://github.com/Xantax/sample_movies

Comment: i think problem is in your _from partial. has it been auto_generated ? or did you code it yourself ?

for info please read form_for api doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

if this does help you, will install moviedb gem to reproduce and fix problem

Comment: I updated the form, but now I get the message about .movie_review undefined method. Could you please replicate the simple app? I'm having problems with this for 2 days.

Comment: I'm at work. Will do that as soon as possible man. Will keep you informed soon. Max tommorow morning ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep working on it myself.

Comment: any news on your side man ?

Comment: Yes, your solution worked for the correct URL. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. Are you still working on it ? Are you facing other issues ? :)

Comment: Yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692437/undefined-method-model-name-for-tmdbmovieclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
<%= link_to "Review it!", new_movie_movie_review_path(@movie) %>
```

By

```
<%= link_to "Review it!", new_movie_movie_review_path(@movie.id) %>
```

Problem is you do not reference movie id but movie object. This is why you have your strange URL parameter.

Once changed, you will have to adapt your MovieReviewsController.

But please be careful, I see you are trying to use "movie review". When I look at link you provided about Tmdb API, I can read " Missing Resources: Review ".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several issues:

`localhost:3000/movies/%23<Tmdb::Movie:0x007ff0608f4398>/movie_reviews/new` this will never work. `Tmdb::Movie:0x007ff0608f4398` is the internal object id of the class instance. The url should look like `localhost:3000/movies/1/movie_reviews/new`. This will allow you to add a new review to the movie with id: 1

In your config/routes.rb file you have declared several urls explicitly and added the root route above other resources. The root route should always be the last declared route. Also `get "movies/show"` and `get "movies/index"` routes are already handled by `resources :movies` so you can remove those.

Routes file should look like this:

```
SampleMovies::Application.routes.draw do 
  resources :movie_reviews
  resources :movies do
    resources :movie_reviews
  end

  root 'movies#index'
end
```

To see all avalaible routes for your application. Go to the project directory and type: `rake routes` It will show all available urls included required and optional parameters.

PS looking at the rest of your code, I strongly advice you to have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html its a most excellent tutorial on the basics of rails.

Comment: I know the URL should look like that, but how do I get the proper movie 'id'? Is this in the show file OK? - <%= link_to "Review it!", new_movie_movie_review_path(@movie) %>