# undefined method `model_name' for Tmdb::Movie:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, themoviedb-api

I'm using this gem - [TMDb](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb) - to build a simple app.

When I visit this URL i get the error:

```
.../movies/97857/movie_reviews/new
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @movie do |movie_form| %>

<%= fields_for :movie_review, @movie.movie_review do |movie_review_fields| %>
  Title : <%= movie_review_fields.text_field :title %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[**Source code**](https://github.com/Xantax/sample_movies)

Comment: can you paste your model in question.

Comment: What model? I provided source code, that's all I have.

Answer (score 1):

[`form_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) expects an `ActiveRecord` object (which has an instance method called `model_name`). `@movie` is a non-ActiveRecord object that comes from the gem you're using and it doesn't have a method called `model_name`. That's why you get the error.

I see that you also have a `Movie` model, but that is not what is used here. From your controller:

```
@movie = Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:movie_id])
```

Since I don't know what you're trying to achieve, I can only point out why you get the error.